# Cannot resolve task not serializable [org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable] Spark Scala RDD

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, rdd

I keep getting the following error stack trace when I try to create an object of a class and call specific methods `newRDD` and `blah`

```
I create a spark shell by importing the jar and run the following in spark-shell

spark-shell --master=yarn --jars=sample_jar.jar --files database.cfg

scala> val reader = new Sample(spark)
scala> val a = reader.buildFileRDD("/xyz/path")

org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable
  at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.ensureSerializable(ClosureCleaner.scala:298)
  at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.org$apache$spark$util$ClosureCleaner$$clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:288)
  at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:108)
  at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.clean(SparkContext.scala:2294)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$filter$1.apply(RDD.scala:387)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$filter$1.apply(RDD.scala:386)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:362)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.filter(RDD.scala:386)
  at Sample.newRDDscala(Sample.scala:117)
  ... 48 elided
Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException:
```

How can I resolve this error?

Comment: can you post this code - DatabaseUtils ?? &  where you are using this - dbObj

Comment: @Srinivas Added more details

Comment: Change dbObj to def or add case before this - DatabaseUtils ? try

Comment: @Srinivas Didnt get that. Can you be give an example?

Comment: If I remove dbUtils I still get an error, but for  File in that case.

Comment: @coderWorld why `DatabseUtils` is not a object,

Comment: @Srinivas If I remove dbUtils entirely, I've another call `val fs = FileSystem.get(sprk.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration)`

Even this throws a similar error that task not serializable. Kindly, check code with another edit.

Comment: can you show exception where it is throwing ??

Comment: @Srinivas Added the other exception. I'm still trying out your suggestion. Checking if it works.

Comment: The thumb rule is, if you are using an object of scala class or object inside spark closure like rdd.map/filter/mapPartitions etc, it must be serialized, hope this helps :)

Comment: where you are using fs, can you move that to function inside whereever you are using ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `DatabaseUtils` code like below & inside class sample remove variables dbConfig & url, add this `val dbObj = new DatabaseUtils(ConfigFactory.parseFile(new File(config)))`

```
class DatabaseUtils(url: String, username: String, password: String) {

  val driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"


  def executeSelectQuery(qry: String): List[String] = {

    var dbString : ArrayBuffer[String] = ArrayBuffer.empty[String]
    var conn:Connection = null
    try {
      Class.forName(driver)
      conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password)
      val statement = conn.createStatement
      val rs = statement.executeQuery(qry)

      while (rs.next) dbString += rs.getString("db_string")

    } catch {
      case e: Exception => e.printStackTrace
    }
    finally {
      conn.close()
    }
    dbString.toList
  }
}

object DatabaseUtils {
 def apply(dbConfig:Config): DatabaseUtils = {
    val url =  "jdbc:mysql://" + dbConfig.getString("db.host") +":"+ dbConfig.getString("db.port") + "/" + dbConfig.getString("db.database") + "?useSSL=false"
    new DatabaseUtils(url, dbConfig.getString("db.username") ,dbConfig.getString("db.password"))
  }
}
```

Comment: can you post complete code & seems your code is not correct & showing compilation errors.

Comment: No the code is correct. It works fine when tested through Spark-shell. It only errors out when I manually create a jar and pass in the jar to spark shell.

Comment: try to reduce variable as much as possible in classes & move it inside object or function

Answer (score 1):

From the stack trace it seems, you are using the object of `DatabaseUtils` inside closure, since `DatabaseUtils` is not serializable it can't be transffered via n/w,  try serializing the `DatabaseUtils`. Also, you can make `DatabaseUtils` `scala object`

```
.. DatabaseUtils extends Serializable
```

Comment: Can you expand on what you mean by "Also, you can make DatabaseUtils scala object" ? Provide an example?

Comment: instead of `class DatabaseUtils(url: String, username: String, password: String)` use `object DatabaseUtils` and move all the fields to the utility. please note that this has nothing to do with serializableException

Comment: Sure I can give that a shot, but how can I resolve the second stack trace which is caused by `val fs = FileSystem.get(sprk.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration)` ?